# Em Portugal "galego(a)" é apelido para "louro(a)"?

Tags: etimologia, vocabulário, diferenças-transatlânticas, dialetos

Em Portugal existe a expressão *"galego(a)"* para se referir a alguém louro/loiro(a) (independente desse alguém ser da Galiza ou não)? Se sim, qual a origem dessa expressão? (Imagino que seja a origem mais óbvia: na Galiza há muitos louros).

Pergunto isso porque no nordeste do Brasil, *"galego"* é um nome usado popularmente para se referir a alguém de cabelos louros e que é geralmente (mas não necessariamente) pobre ou com pouca instrução. Por exemplo, *"Me apaixonei pela galega do meu bairro..."*.

Se essa expressão não é de origem portuguesa, como ela surgiu no nordeste brasileiro?

Eu acho que essa expressão não pode ter se originado no Brasil. É mais plausível que tenha se originado em Portugal, talvez no norte, onde a Galiza faz fronteira.  Isso faria bastante sentido, pois é do norte de Portugal de onde vieram muitos colonizadores (e consequentemente o vocabulário e a fala) do nordeste brasileiro.

Os dicionários [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/galego), [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/galego) e [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=&t=&palavra=galego) incluem esse sentido para o verbete "galego" e afirmam que esse sentido é usado no nordeste do Brasil, mas não fala nada sobre o uso em Portugal.

Comment: *Galego* no Brasil (segundo o Aulete) também pode designar 'pessoa nascida em Portugal, especialmente de pouca instrução'. Este uso é claramente criação brasileira. Não poderá aceção 'pessoa loira' ser um especialização da aceção 'pessoa nascida em Portugal'? É possível que a proporção de loiros fosse bastante maior entre os recém-chegados de Portugal do que entre os nascidos já no Brasil (com a miscigenação, e talvez numa fase inicial da colonização viesse mais gente do sul de Portugal, e mais tarde mais do norte).

Comment: Sim, não tinha pensado nisso. A primeira coisa que me veio a cabeça é de que seria uma criação portuguesa "importada", que me parecia ser a mais plausível. Eu modifiquei o post perguntando pela origem do sentido brasileiro.

Comment: Nunca ouvi este sentido ("Português com pouca instrução") por aqui, talvez seja antigo e esteja em desuso? E como você disse, pode ser que o sentido "louro com pouca instrução" seja uma especialização de "português com pouca instrução" (que por sua vez pode ser a versão "importada" do sentido pejorativo originado em Portugal: "alguém pobre/com pouca instrução", o sentido que você disse no outro comentário). São suposições.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não.
Nunca ouvi essa expressão em Portugal; só no Brasil, na região da Bahia.

E para cimentar a minha experiência, segue isto:

No Norte Português há cabelos alourados, que nos ficaram provavelmente do tempo das invasões viking ou dos tempos celtas... e com certeza que na Galiza se passa o mesmo.
Mais ainda: a etnografia, cultura, e sociedades minhota e galega são indissociáveis, e os povos misturavam-se natural e frequentemente.

Sendo os minhotos e os galegos tão semelhantes, não **acho** que fizesse sentido chamar de "galego" um loiro, no norte de Portugal, porque os locais também teriam percentagem semelhante de loiros.
Não seria uma qualidade que ajudasse a classificar alguém como galego ou nortenho.

Comment: Seria essa expressão criada no Brasil? E talvez influenciada pela influência portuguesa ou por algum estereótipo de que todo minhoto é galego... Acho pouco provável que seja isso, ainda mais porque essa expressão é restrita mais ao nordeste do Brasil. Estou pesquisando por ocorrências antigas dessa expressão, mas é bastante difícil filtrar os resultados em que "galego" ou "galega" se refiram especificamente a louro.

Comment: Boa pergunta, @Seninha, não faço ideia. Só sei com certeza que, vivendo no norte de Portugal e passando bastante tempo no Minho em casa de família, não reconheço a expressão "galego".

Comment: Aqui no sul também não. A única conotação figurada de "galego" que eu conheço, é 'pessoa pobre, que trabalha muito, fazendo muitas vezes trabalhos que os outros não querem fazer. Que ficou provavelmente de imigração galega para Portugal nos séculos XIX e XX.

Comment: É mais comum, em alguns sítios, chamarem "russos" aos loiros.

Comment: Já agora, aqui em Braga pelo menos, galega pode ser um insulto, chamando a pessoa de vaca: "Sua galega!".

Comment: @JorgeB., mas isso é "ruço".

Comment: @Jacinto sim é isso. Peço desculpa pela confusão.

Comment: @JorgeB., pá, pede-me desculpa quando me pisares um calo; por uma confusão não vale a pena :)

Comment: ANeves, essa dos cabelos louros nos ficarem dos vikings parece-me duvidosa. Não eram só eles que tinham cabelo louro, e nem me parece que cá tenham ficado muitos. Antes deles vieram celtas e suevos. Os celtas, provavelmente em quantidade apreciável; os romanos acharam que o povo da antiga Galécia---Galiza e norte de Portugal--era aparentado com os gauleses e gente do País de Gales; daí os nomes parecidos Galicia, Gália, Gales. Além disso tu tens loiros em todo o sul da Europa. Até na Geórgia, que fica lá para os lados do Irão; há um georgiano loiro no Chaves.

Comment: Antes da colonização romana, a região era povoada pelos celtíberos, os lusitanos, e outros povos celtas. Eu aceitei a resposta, mas adicionei outra pergunta à minha postagem perguntando a etimologia de "galego" para o sentido brasileiro.

Comment: @Jacinto os louros da Ucrânia, Geórgia, etc, [vieram de cima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rus%27_people), da Escandinávia. São «Rus'». Ou estou a pensar errado?

Comment: E Jacinto, encontrei isto interessante sobre os vikings e as expansões deles: [um mapa das expansões](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Viking_Expansion.svg) (chegaram a colonizar o mediterrâneo central?!?); um artigo da Wikipedia sobre [Vikings na Ibéria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikings_in_Iberia); e as [siglas poveiras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siglas_poveiras), vestígios interessantíssimos de cultural viking na Póvoa do Varzim.

Comment: @ANeves. Sim, os Rus' migraram pro leste europeu, miscigenando com os eslavos e dando o nome à Russia. Os Vikings ibéricos são pós-latinos (vieram das invasões bárbaras que deram fim ao império romano) e eram principalmente Francos (da França). Já os celtas ibéricos são pré-latinos. Para a influência desses dois povos no nosso vocabulário: [palavras celtas no galego](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Galician_words_of_Celtic_origin) (muitas também se aplicam ao português) e [palavras francas no português](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Portuguese_words_of_Germanic_origin#Frankish)

Comment: @ANeves, da Geórgia, duvido. De Kiev a Tiblisi ainda são 1500 km em linha reta. Mesmo à Ucrânia e Rússia, duvido que alguma vez tenham sido uma proporção significativa da população. O Alexandre o Grande era louro, séculos antes da expansão vinking. Há louros pela Europa toda; não creio que sejam nem sequer maioritariamente de origem escandinava. Os olhos azuis, que andam frequentemente associados a cabelo loiro, evoluíram, ao que li algures, pelas bandas do Mar Negro já há uns milhares de anos.

Comment: @Seninha, creio que os vinkings a que o ANeves se refere não são os godos que invadiram e se instalaram no império romano por volta do sV, e que vieram por terra; são os escandinavos que vinham mais tarde de barco saquear.

Comment: Pronto, desisto, estou claramente fora da minha água!! :)

Comment: @Jacinto: _Gales_, _Gauleses_, _Gália_, _Galícia_, _Galiza_ são tudo expressões que designam «país dos **celtas**». Apesar de em português «celta» se pronunciar qualquer coisa como [sæltə], em inglês (e outras línguas) a pronúncia é com o som /k/, ou seja, [kæltə], que em português poderíamos transcrever como «quelta». Passar de /k/ para /g/ é muito frequente. Os Celtas não eram predominantemente louros de olhos azuis.

Answer (score 5):

Minha experiência é que

1. "Galego", no **Rio de Janeiro**, quarenta anos atrás, significava "português". A etimologia disso parece ser que o governo português, em algum momento da primeira metade do século XX, proibiu a emigração para o Brasil, resultando em uma corrente migratória que passava pela Galícia - ou pelo menos, por um passaporte espanhol falsificado, em que a Galícia aparecia como lugar de origem. O uso estava muito relacionado à ampla presença de imigrantes portugueses e seus descendentes no pequeno comércio carioca - particularmente padarias e botequins. Embora não fosse tecnicamente errado chamar um português assalariado de "galego", a palavra evocava quase sempre um pequeno comerciante de origem portuguesa. Uma pessoa loira pobre ou ignorante não precisava de um termo específico, por que, quase por definição, não existia.
2. "Galego", em **Porto Alegre**, entre trinta e quarenta anos atrás, não tinha nenhum significado popular. Era apenas o demônimo para alguém nascido na Galícia, e usado bastante raramente - um espanhol, mesmo nascido na Galícia, seria mais comumente "espanhol", ou, é claro, "castelhano". Um português seria "português", ou, geralmente em contextos pejorativos, "luso" ou "lusitano". Uma pessoa loira pobre ou ignorante seria um "alemão" (feminino "alemoa", não "alemã") ou um "lambote", ou, se de origem evidentemente italiana, um "gringo".
3. "Galego", em **Brasília**, de trinta anos para cá, quer dizer "loiro", mas com um aspecto pejorativo, geralmente associado com pobreza ou ignorância, embora também possa ser simplesmente má-vontade do falante ("A esposa do deputado é uma galega muito metida a besta"). Esse uso é de origem nordestina, e talvez tenha sido muito popularizado pela composição "Galeguim do Zói Azul", de Genival Lacerda.

Minha impressão é que o uso nordestino vem se generalizando, e a acepção carioca, à medida que os portugueses donos de boteco vão rareando, está caindo em desuso.

Answer (score 1):

Na zona de Lisboa, onde resido, nunca ouvi a designação de «galego» para «loiro»; embora hoje em dia seja bastante rara essa associação, tal como o @Jacinto mencionou num comentário, os «galegos» eram normalmente pessoas com relativamente pouca instrução, fazendo trabalhos que mais ninguém queria fazer, oriundos das sucessivas migrações de pessoas originárias da Galiza nos séculos XIX e XX. Tanto era assim que muitos não tinham dinheiro para viver e trabalhar em Lisboa; moravam do outro lado do rio, naquilo a que durante décadas e até 1930 se chamou *Aldeia Galega do Ribatejo* (apesar de já ter na altura o estatuto de *vila* e sede de concelho) — hoje a cidade do [Montijo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montijo).

Há outras «Aldeias Galegas» pelo país fora — por exemplo, [ao pé da cidade de Alenquer](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldeia_Galega_da_Merceana) —
que, devido a sua relativa proximidade à capital, muito provavelmente tiveram a mesma origem: galegos imigrados que necessitavam de um local barato para viver.

A partir de meados do século XX (segundo o meu pai!), muitos galegos escapavam ao regime espanhol (não que o nosso, na altura, fosse muito melhor...) em alturas de profunda miséria, mas estes frequentemente iam trabalhar em restaurantes. É tradicional encontrar restaurantes (especialmente nos maiores agregados populacionais, do Tejo para cima) chamados «O Galego», que, na sua origem, teriam sido realmente abertos por galegos imigrados. Nestes casos, no entanto, e pelo menos na zona de Lisboa, onde resido, a imagem associada aos galegos é extremamente positiva: ao contrário da ideia dos «pobres galegos sem instrução», a ideia que temos por aqui (ou que tínhamos há 3 décadas...) é que os galegos que para cá vieram, sim, estavam a escapar da pobreza atroz — mas eram esforçados, trabalhadores, dedicados, empreendedores, e, em geral, adorados pelos seus colegas (e clientes).

É evidente que esta é uma imagem que os lisboetas podem ter de uma região de Espanha que é geográfica e culturalmente próxima de nós (o galego será porventura a língua ibérica mais próxima do português, já que o mirandês, a segunda língua oficial de Portugal, está mais próximo do leonês) — apesar da distância de Lisboa à fronteira com a Galiza ser considerável — e que por isso seja profundamente diferente daquela que têm os «vizinhos» minhotos e transmontanos.

Já os espanhóis em geral, tal como o @Rogério afirma, não têm assim grande respeito pelos galegos (mas isso é verdade de todas as regiões de Espanha em relação a todas as restantes regiões...), independentemente da sua distância geográfica; isso, pelo menos, era o que afirmava uma amiga minha, oriunda do sul da Andaluzia, que viveu grande parte da sua vida em Madrid, e depois veio viver para Lisboa durante bastantes anos (agora está algures na América Latina, acho eu). De certa forma, ela achava «estranha» a curiosa admiração e consideração que os lisboetas tinham pelos galegos, quando ela — enquanto natural da Andaluzia — não tinha nada essa impressão. Ela justificava isso com a aparente «ilusão» que os lisboetas têm relativamente aos galegos, considerando-os «muito próximos dos portugueses, especialmente os do Norte de Portugal» — quando isso não é lá muito bem verdade.

Os poucos galegos que conheço pessoalmente tinham todos um carinho especial para com os portugueses e um profundo ódio e desprezo aos castelhanos e demais regiões espanholas; isto é bem visível, por exemplo, quando se vê a forma como os turistas portugueses são tratados na Galiza comparados com os turistas de outras regiões de Espanha. Ironicamente, devido à política Franquista (o tempo da ditadura em Espanha), a língua e cultura espanholas (leia-se: imposta de Madrid...) foram implantadas «à força» na Galiza, há muitas e muitas décadas atrás, e, da perspectiva de um português, os galegos (pelo menos os que têm menos de 80 anos...) são muito mais «espanhóis» do que qualquer outra coisa. Isso reflecte-se não só na forma como falam — os que já aprenderam galego falam-no com um forte sotaque castelhano, quando se pode ver pelos idosos que ainda aprenderam galego antes de ser proibido (ou seja, antes de 1939, mais ou menos), têm um sotaque que, para um lisboeta, é impossível de distinguir do sotaque minhoto. A sério. Até faz confusão. Apesar do castelhano ter 95% de semelhanças com o léxico português, a verdade é que usa um vocabulário muito diferente (não quer dizer que as palavras não existam em português; são é usadas com significados completamente diferentes; e estou a falar do vocabulário do dia-a-dia, pois, talvez de forma pouco intuitiva, é no vocabulário mais «exótico» que se encontram mais semelhanças). Já o galego, pelo menos historicamente, usa expressões que são comuns de ambos os lados do Rio Minho (mesmo que a grafia seja *ligeiramente* diferente); quando usam essas expressões com o sotaque *genuíno* do galego, são indistinguíveis do português tal como é falado no Minho. Isso foi algo que só notei quando estive no sul da Galiza e tive a sorte de encontrar alguns idosos a falarem galego «genuíno».

Já o pessoal que aprendeu galego depois da democracia, falam-no como «segunda língua» (a primeira sendo o castelhano), com um sotaque e vocabulários tipicamente castelhanos, mesmo que efectivamente estejam a falar uma língua diferente, e, apesar de terem *imensa* boa vontade (têm mesmo!), têm uma *enorme* dificuldade em entender o português corrente (mesmo que o consigam ler e compreender). Consta que as novas gerações, que já aprendem galego praticamente à nascença e o podem praticar com os avós (e não com os pais), estão a voltar a ganhar o sotaque «genuíno» do galego. Mas não conheço nenhum caso pessoalmente, pelo que não posso dizer nada. Apenas posso dizer que, ao ver/ouvir a TV Galicia, ainda acho que a maioria dos locutores fala o galego com forte pronúncia castelhana... apesar de, se calhar, entre os espanhóis, eles não acharem o mesmo.

Seja como for, para mim, louros são os madrilenos (e os andaluzes), não os galegos; esses, pelo menos para mim, são tão louros como os minhotos (ou seja, claro que há galegos louros, como há minhotos louros, mas não são tantos como isso). Isso não é de admirar, já que a Galiza e o Norte de Portugal tiveram imensa influência celta — tal como o País de Gales e a Escócia — e os celtas tinham pele clara e olhos possivelmente claros, mas não eram necessariamente louros. Na Irlanda, as pessoas são desproporcionadamente ruivas — mas muito mais provavelmente devido às invasões dinamarquesas («vikings») do que propriamente por haverem mais celtas louros nessa zona. As zonas também tradicionalmente celtas de França e da Suíça têm igualmente uma proporção de poucos louros — talvez mais do que na Galiza, mas isso é porque se misturaram muito mais com os germânicos que, esses sim, eram louros.

Ademais, os ibéricos que são louros são muito provavelmente descendentes de suevos e visigodos, tribos genuinamente germânicas, que estabeleceram os seus reinos no norte da península; durante a invasão muçulmana, esses suevos, visogodos e demais tribos germânicas foram «empurrados» para as montanhas das Astúrias, e por isso é que não é de admirar que haja aí uma enorme concentração de louros. Mas não no Norte de Portugal ou na Galiza, em que a população local — celtibera — apenas «mudou» de governantes ao longo dos milénios, mas manteve-se mais ou menos coesa (a nobreza visigótica não se iria misturar *muito* com os «nativos» que eram seus vassalos... o que não quer dizer que não se tenham casado com estes... mas a relativa baixa proporção de louros mostra que isso não aconteceu com tanta frequência como isso).

Enfim, é complicado, e muito mais complicado a partir do século XX, em que a deslocação de populações em massa entre toda a Europa passou a ser muito mais simples do que no passado, e, hoje em dia, é muito mais difícil encontrar populações perfeitamente isoladas que não tenham sido «contaminadas» por essas sucessivas migrações. Por exemplo, é evidente que era no interesse do governo central de Madrid, durante a ditadura, fazer questão em transferir muitos castelhanos para a Galiza, para deliberadamente *suprimirem* a cultura e língua galegas; em consequência disso, não me custa a acreditar que tenha havido muito mais «mistura» entre galegos e outros espanhóis não-galegos a partir dos meados do século XX, que depois se traduziu numa muito maior diversidade de populações.

Posso dizer, isso sim, que da perspectiva de uma *lisboeta*, não consigo distinguir *fisicamente* os galegos dos demais espanhóis, mas consigo distingui-los dos *portugueses*. Não é fácil de explicar porquê, já que as diferenças são mesmo muito subtis, e os portugueses, como disse, são fisicamente muito variados, com imensas origens e misturas. Como se dizia antigamente, não há português vivo hoje em dia que não tenha antepassados brancos, negros, ciganos, judeus, ou muçulmanos. O herdeiro ao trono de Portugal é descendente de Maomé — a única casa real europeia que pode genuinamente traçar um dos seus ramos a partir do profeta — apesar de ser um bom católico (e a sua família o é desde o século X pelo menos, se não antes), ter quase dois metros de altura, e ser louro de pele muito clara, típica da nobreza alemã da qual descende muito mais directamente...

É óbvio que nem todos os portugueses têm sangue real ;-) mas que isto é uma grande misturada, lá isso é. Curiosamente, com tanta mistura, o património genético dos portugueses é surpreendentemente muito mais uniforme (e distinto!) do que o da maior parte dos povos europeus (incluindo Espanha). A explicação para este «facto» (estudado em detalhe no início da década de 2010) é de que os portugueses, apesar das suas múltiplas origens e misturas, habitaram o mesmo espaço em contínuo durante pelo menos 900 anos (ou 3300 anos, se pensarmos em Lisboa), e, por terem sido relativamente pobres durante a maioria da sua história (com breves períodos excepcionais), viajavam muito pouco, limitando-se às suas fronteiras, que são as mais antigas estabelecidas na Europa (e que se mantiveram na mesma durante quase 900 anos). Isso misturou-nos tanto entre nós — apesar de tanta diversidade! — que ficámos geneticamente uniformes (mesmo que do ponto de vista da *expressão* do genoma possamos ser muito diferentes!); talvez seja essa a razão pela qual é-me muito mais fácil distinguir um português de um espanhol do que um galego dum castelhano, leonês, andaluz, madrileno... apesar de teoricamente termos muito mais em comum com os galegos.

Enfim, desculpem a divagação, mas queria apenas explicar porque é que, para mim, não faz qualquer sentido chamar «galegos» às pessoas loiras, e, de facto, nunca ouvi tal coisa aqui na região de Lisboa...

Answer (score 0):

Meu avô era português da região de Trás-os-montes e, para ele, a pior ofensa possível era ser chamado de galego. Talvez, adicionado às questões migratórias, pode haver a questão da separação do condado portucalense do Reino da Galícia. Outro fator que pode estar relacionado a isto é o fato dos galegos serem considerados no passado, pelos demais espanhóis,  como pessoas inferiores, especialmente pela diferença idiomática e considerados preguiçosos, algo parecido com o que acontecia com os alentejanos em Portugal e os baianos no Brasil, tidos como preguiçosos também.

Answer (score 0):

Sou de uma região do norte Catarinanse colonizada por alemães, italianos húngaros e poloneses, que na sua grande maioria são loiros de olhos azuis, assim como a maioria dos meus familiares.  Quando vou para a capital, ilha de  Florianópolis, eles me classificam como "galega". Na primeira vez que eu fui estranhei muito esse vocabulário e a resposta para a minha indagação foi porque eu era loira de olhos azuis. Não tinha nada de pejorativo. Era uma classificação: moreno x galego. Acho q depende muito da região. Se analisarmos melhor, o estado SC não é grande, agora imaginem isso a  nível nacional... deve ter inúmeros sinônimos ou classificação para essa mesma palavra. Até porque os primeiros colonos europeus,  não tinham muita instrução e dinheiro quando aqui aportaram.  Fizeram "grana" com muito suor e trabalho, lavrando a sua terra. Diferente da cultura que encontraram aqui, com uso de escravos.